# Convert to USDZ from Cinema 4D

Tags: cinema4d

I have a designed a model in Cinema4D. That I need to export in USDZ format to use in 3D warehouse app of Shopify. But I can find no working way of converting may design to USDZ from my Windows PC. I found no working converter on the internet. Can anyone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 (Mac and PC): I found the "easiest" way requires the use (and some knowledge) of Substance Painter which I own (they have a free 30 day trial). https://www.substance3d.com/buy/download

Export your model in C4D as an .fbx file which you then import into Painter. From Painter you create a "File / New..." Project. You then "Select..." your .fbx file from the dialogue that pops up. Your model should appear in the 3d view (adding any textures or materials requires knowledge of Painter).

You can then "File / Export Textures..." and in the window that pops up for exporting textures set the Config to "USD PBR Metal Roughness", then hit the "Export" button in the bottom right corner. After export is finished view the folder and a .usdz file is created which technically would have static model with textures embedded.

Method 2 (Mac Only): Get an Apple Developer account and download the USDPython tool (Current version 0.60) that they have to create .usdz files. Very technical, but doable. https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: for the Mac route there's this workflow https://github.com/PRFTDigitalLabs/c4d-usdz-sample you can read more here https://blog.truthlabs.com/adventures-in-3d-a-cinema-4d-to-ios-ar-quicklook-usdz-workflow-conversion-animation-texturing-4dcfdbab8996